# how can i pass url variables not in english

Tags: url, utf-8, urlvariables

i have some code that sends me to a url website and the url has a username and password variables in it. when the username and password are in english it works well and it signs the user in.
(for example http://mywebsite.example?username=john&password=qwerty)

but when i send the variables in hebrew (in my case) i get an error saying incorrect URL or login info.
(for example [http://mywebsite.example?username=ראובןהגבר&password=qwerty](http://mywebsite.example?username=%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%95%D7%91%D7%9F%D7%94%D7%92%D7%91%D7%A8&password=qwerty))

At first I tried to encode the username in UTF-8 so it matches the website encoding but that didn't work. what is the problem and how can i fix it? Thanks

Comment: Are you typing the URLs into the browser address bar or are you using some library in a script?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) is what you need to use, but it's hard to tell you how to do it without knowing what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: @lenz typing them into the address bar

Comment: Okay, URL-encoding by hand is like calculating square roots with your mind only. It's no fun for most people. And it's not really about programming.

Comment: But I'm curious: how did you encode the username with UTF-8? Or what did you try there?